# Icon size increased (too large) after update

Tags: unity, 16.04, nautilus, icons

I am running ubuntu 16.04, after updating the system yesterday the icon size increased abruptly. How can I revert back to the normal icon size? Also now the nautilus has two maximize, minimize, close buttons in the maximized mode. Also Nautilus is not showing the hard drive that I have mounted in the side pain (Although I can access the drive by going to the mount point). The icon size is changed on the desktop as well.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the culprit, The newer version of nautilus is not good. Reverted back to the older version of nautilus and now its working perfectly fine. 
Also in the newer version there is no option for Edit->preferences->Icon view defaults->Icons zoom level.

nautilus-data:amd64 (1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu5, 1:3.18.5-0ubuntu1~xenial1)

nautilus:amd64 (1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu5, 1:3.18.5-0ubuntu1~xenial1)